# wireless isn't working 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless

friends, two days I'm working, I try to do something from domestic and foreign forums, but did not. I would appreciate if you can help.

a) I installed updates.

b) can connect to wired

c) I installed Windows 7 side, working wireless as entered in the windows

d) The fn + f3 to open wireless key that does not work, does not come on when the wireless signal ubuntu.

shut down the computer screen shows:

```
                                ubuntu 14.04
                                                ..... reboot: system halted
*stopping rsync daemon rsync                                        [OK]
*speech-dispatcher disabled ; edit/etc/default/speech-dispatcher
*asking all remaining processes to terminate...                     [OK]
all processes ended within 1 seconds...                             [OK]   
modemManager[640]: <info> Caught signal, shutting down...
modemManager[640]: <info> modemManager is shutting down
```

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 420M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1692] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:036d]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6603]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

iwlist scanning

```
wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that copy-pasting options is the best way to ask a question. Personally, **strong text** doesn't really tell me what's going on.

Comment: sorry, I've editted the my question

Comment: Well, from what that shows, there isn't a shutdown problem. If it's hanging, just let it sit for a while and see what happens. What's the model of your WiFi card? Run `lspci` in the terminal and put the output here.

Comment: Did your computer ever shutdown?  Are you able to shut your computer down.  If you are able to shut your computer down, please consider changing the title of your question.  It appears by looking at the comments and details of your question that you might be having an issue with your wireless adapter.  If you put your question related to your wireless adapter you'll get better attention by people who have expertise with networking.  I looked to find out how to help you to shutdown your computer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkil list` terminal command.

Comment: That was a typo. It is `rfkill list`.

Comment: The wifi is hardware blocked. This is probably a hardware switch or bios setting.

Comment: computer starts "PNP bios fault", etc.